# Why there are almost no book for revenue analytic?

Tags: finance, financial-engineering

Why there are almost no book for revenue analytic?

By revenue analytic, it is meant to be predicting the revenue of a firm in the future

Comment: try searching revenue forecasting instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many books about revenue analytic and management:

[**1.Segmentation, Revenue Management and Pricing Analytic(2014).**](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0124166989)

[**2.Revenue Management(2011)**](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0307788989)

[**3.Revenue vs. needs : an analytical approach**](http://books.google.com/books?id=issiAQAAMAAJ)

[**4.Freemium Economics: Leveraging Analytics and User Segmentation to Drive    Revenue(2013)**](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0124166989)

[**5.Marketing Analytics: Strategic Models and Metrics(2013)**](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=1481900307)